# Angular JS: orderBy with function not working

Tags: angularjs

My html:

```
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="">Name</a></th>
            <th><a href="">Issued shares</a></th>
            <th><a href="">Closing price</a></th>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="predicateBlueChip = 'marketCap()'; reverseBlueChip = !reverseBlueChip">Market capitalisation</a></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="listing in listings | orderBy:predicateBlueChip:reverseBlueChip">
            <td><a ng-href="#/browse/listing/{{ listing.id }}">{{ listing.name_short }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ listing.last_price.issued_shares }}</td>
            <td>{{ listing.last_price.price_close }}</td>
            <td>{{ marketCap(listing) | currency:'R' }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Controller:

```
   $scope.predicateBlueChip = 'marketCap()';
    $scope.reverseBlueChip = true;

    $scope.marketCap = function(listing) {
        return Math.round(listing.last_price.price_close * listing.last_price.issued_shares / 1000000);
    }
```

The orderBy doesn't work, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong; the numerous other posts about orderBy didn't solve my problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression should be a function, and not a string containing a function call.

Remove this line:

```
$scope.predicateBlueChip = 'marketCap()';
```

And use the `marketCap` function directly:

```
<tr ng-repeat="listing in listings | orderBy:marketCap:reverseBlueChip">
```

Comment: I want to be able to sort it with the other headers as well (I just took it out to avoid confusion). So the orderBy must be the predicate property on the scope. How do I assign marketCap to the predicate for it to work?

Comment: `$scope.predicateBlueChip = $scope.marketCap;` (but this line must go after `$scope.marketCap` has been defined.

Comment: Thanks, for completeness: `ng-click="predicate = marketCap;` and `<td>{{ marketCap(listing) | currency:'R' }}</td>` and `$scope.predicate = $scope.marketCap;` works (fyi I removed the bluechip)